# mysql update with 2 joins

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-update

I need some assistance updating a table in MySQL.  It would be with 2 joins to the same table.  its for BLOG site where I want to add a new field to link to.   I created a new field in the article table. For a BLOG Post you need a Category and a Sub-Category.   The categories are in a table called CATEGORIES.   When you post the article the field IDTOP_ART contains the primary key for the category you selected.   When I first did the website i have Title_ART take the text (Title_SUB) for the subcategory.  I want to switch it to an int field Title_Art_ID.    I need to update that new field with the primary key from the subcategory Table.

Articles Table

+-----------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|    IDTOP_ART      Title_ART       Message         Title_Art_ID  |

---

```
10      PERSON          TEXT
10      VEHICLE         TEXT
4       GENERAL         TEXT
```

SUB-CATEGORY TABLE

|   RECORDID    TOP_SUB     TITLE_SUB   |

---

```
1       10      PERSON
2       10      VEHICLE
3       4       GENERAL
4       6       vEHICLE
```

I tried this but it did not work.

update pin_article_art art
inner join pin_subcategory_sub SUB on
   art.title_art = SUB.title_sub
inner join pin_subcategory_sub SUB2 on
   art.idtop_art = SUB2.top_sub
set art.title_art_id = SUB2.id_sub

There appear to be issues because you could have some categories with a sub-category that has the same text (Title_SUB) but different RECORDID.

Comment: Why do you have a separate sub-category table? I would suggest using one table `CATEGORY` with `category_id, category_name, category_parent_id`

Comment: unfortunately I have had the current setup installed for years so past archive data would not be valid right?